# Azure Function No authentication handlers are registered

Tags: azure-functions

I'm trying to create a simple V2 Azure Function. It can be Anonymous auth level because it will be secured by API Management.

The constructor and function can be seen below:

```
        public ProvideOfsPortfolioData(IMediator mediatorService, IInstrumentationService instrumentationService, ILogger<ProvideOfsPortfolioData> logger)
        {
            _mediatorService = mediatorService;
            _instrumentationService = instrumentationService;
            _logger = logger;
            _typeName = "Interfaces.Ce.Presentation.AzureFunctions.ProvideOfsPortfolioData";
        }

        [FunctionName("ProvideOfsPortfolioData")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{_typeName}.Run] - Started");
        }
```

When I try to debug by hitting F5 in VS2019, I get the following error in the console window:

```
An unhandled host error has occurred.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core: No authentication handlers
are registered. Did you forget to call
AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("WebJobsAuthLevel",...)?.
```

Content of Startup.cs is as follows:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Interfaces.Ce.Presentation.AzureFunctions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Startup.
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _metadataTokens;

        // Public Methods.
        #region PublicMethods

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder"></param>
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            // Get Service Configuration.
            ReadServiceConfiguration();

            // Add framework services.
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            builder.Services.AddLookupService(_metadataTokens);
            builder.Services.AddCrmService(_metadataTokens);
            builder.Services.AddInstrumentationService(_metadataTokens);

            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IMandateService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.MandateService)));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPolicyService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PolicyService)));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPortfolioService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PortfolioService)));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IReviewService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.ReviewService)));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IContactService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.ContactService)));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IInvestmentProfileService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InvestmentProfileService)));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(ISystemUserService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.SystemUserService)));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(ITeamService), Type.GetType(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.TeamService)));

            // =======================
            // MediatR Initialisation.
            // =======================
            builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IMediator), typeof(Mediator));
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ServiceFactory>(p => p.GetService);
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPreProcessorBehavior<,>));
            builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>));

            // ============================
            // MediatR Pipeline Extensions.
            // ============================
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PipelineProcessingRequestValidationEnabled)))
            {
                builder.Services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv =>
                    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<
                        Application.Portfolio.Commands.AssignSinglePortfolio.Validator>());
                builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehaviour<,>));
            }
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PipelineProcessingPerformanceBehaviourEnabled)))
            {
                builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPerformanceBehaviour<,>));
            }

            // ========================================
            // MediatR - Commands/Queries Registration.
            // ========================================
            builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(Application.Portfolio.Commands.AssignSinglePortfolio.Request).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);


        }

        #endregion

        // Private Methods.
        #region PrivateMethods

        /// <summary>
        /// Read Configuration.
        /// </summary>
        private void ReadServiceConfiguration()
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            ValidateServiceConfiguration(config);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validate Configuration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        private void ValidateServiceConfiguration(IConfigurationRoot config)
        {
            _metadataTokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // Mandatory Service Configuration Keys.
            var listofkeys = new List<string>()
            {
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PipelineProcessingRequestValidationEnabled,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PipelineProcessingPerformanceBehaviourEnabled,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.MandateService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PolicyService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.PortfolioService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.ReviewService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.ContactService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InvestmentProfileService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.SystemUserService,
                LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.TeamService
            };

            // Check for mandatory keys.
            foreach (var key in listofkeys)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[key]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"the configuration key [{key}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(key, config[key]);
            }

            // Check for optional keys driven off condition flags.

            // Lookup Service Is Enabled.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsEnabled]))
            {
                throw new Exception($"the configuration key [{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsEnabled}] is null of empty!");
            }
            _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsEnabled, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsEnabled]);

            // Crm Service Is Enabled.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiIsEnabled]))
            {
                throw new Exception($"the configuration key [{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiIsEnabled}] is null of empty!");
            }
            _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiIsEnabled, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiIsEnabled]);

            // Authentication Service Is Enabled.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceIsEnabled]))
            {
                throw new Exception($"the configuration key [{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceIsEnabled}] is null of empty!");
            }
            _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceIsEnabled, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceIsEnabled]);

            // Instrumentation Service Is Enabled.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiIsEnabled]))
            {
                throw new Exception($"the configuration key [{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiIsEnabled}] is null of empty!");
            }
            _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiIsEnabled, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiIsEnabled]);

            // If Enabled - Lookup Service Api Validation.
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsEnabled)))
            {
                // Mandatory.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiBaseAddress]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"lookup service api key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiBaseAddress}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiBaseAddress,
                    config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiBaseAddress]);

                // Mandatory.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiSubscriptionKey])
                )
                {
                    throw new Exception($"lookup service api key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiSubscriptionKey}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiSubscriptionKey,
                    config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiSubscriptionKey]);


                // Mandatory.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsCachingEnabled]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"lookup service api key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsCachingEnabled}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsCachingEnabled,
                    config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiIsCachingEnabled]);


                // Optional.
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiCacheProviderServiceTypeName,
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(
                        config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiCacheProviderServiceTypeName])
                        ? string.Empty
                        : config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.LookupServiceApiCacheProviderServiceTypeName]);
            }

            // If Enabled - Crm Service Api Validation.
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiIsEnabled)))
            {
                // Mandatory.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiBaseAddress]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"crm service api key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiBaseAddress}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiBaseAddress,
                    config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceApiBaseAddress]);

                // Mandatory.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceTimeout]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"crm service timeout:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceTimeout}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceTimeout,
                    config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.CrmServiceTimeout]);

                if (!Convert.ToBoolean(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceIsEnabled)))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Service dependency exception, Authentication Service must be enabled in conjunction with Crm Service. Check Configuration!");
                }
            }

            // If Enabled - Authentication Service APi Validation.
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceIsEnabled)))
            {
                // Mandatory.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceAuthorityUrl]))
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        $"authentication service key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceAuthorityUrl}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceAuthorityUrl, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceAuthorityUrl]);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceClientId]))
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        $"authentication service key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceClientId}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceClientId, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceClientId]);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceRedirectUrl]))
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        $"authentication service key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceRedirectUrl}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceRedirectUrl, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceRedirectUrl]);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceSecret]))
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        $"authentication service key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceSecret}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceSecret, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.AuthenticationServiceSecret]);
            }

            // If Enabled - Instrumentation Service APi Validation.
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(_metadataTokens.ReadString(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiIsEnabled)))
            {
                // Mandatory.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiSubscriptionKey]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"instrumentation data logger api subscription key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiSubscriptionKey}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(
                    LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiSubscriptionKey, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiSubscriptionKey]);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiBaseAddress]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"instrumentation data logger service api base address key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiBaseAddress}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiBaseAddress, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceApiBaseAddress]);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceMessageAction]))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"instrumentation data logger service message action key:[{LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceMessageAction}] is null or empty!");
                }
                _metadataTokens.Add(LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceMessageAction, config[LocalSettings.ServiceConfigurationKeys.InstrumentationServiceMessageAction]);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

How should I add the required handler?

Comment: Can you please add your `Startup.cs` as well ?

Comment: @HariHaran I have now added

Comment: Can you quickly check if changing the function to `static` makes it work ? or still throws error ?

Comment: @HariHaran I get the same error if I make the function static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some code is trying to utilize the AspNetCore.Authentication.Core module for authentication. When using authentication, it's up to the user to select an Auth provider. In this case, the AddAuthentication() command is not called in the startup.cs file. More documentation on this is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.0#authentication-middleware-and-services

In this particular instance, the following code was identified as making the call to the Authentication module:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv =>
                    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<
                        Application.Portfolio.Commands.AssignSinglePortfolio.Validator>());
                builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehaviour<,>));
```

As the objective is anonymous auth, this has been commented out to resolve the issue.