# API key authentication with azure functions

Tags: .net, azure, function, .net-core, api-key

I'm trying to change the authorization level from Anonymous to Function for a azure function but I'm getting the same error message: *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core: No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?.*

According to the docs, you shouldn't have to do anything else besides changing the authorization level and then using a correct api key when doing the request so i'm not sure what to do here. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Azure Functions version 3
.NET core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of your code is trying to use the `AspNetCore.Authentication.Core` module for ***authentication***. By using the authentication, it's up to the user to select an Auth provider. More documentation on this is available here: [authentication middleware and services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.0#authentication-middleware-and-services)

Refer here for similar kind of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734227/15997690)

Refer [here for securing azure functions using api keys](https://damienbod.com/2020/08/17/securing-azure-functions-using-api-keys/)